# How to find child nodes in an iframe with angular and style them?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, iframe, viewchild

I need a way to find the child nodes inside of an iframe with angular (I need the html element). My current approach looks like this:

*I placed a reference variable in my iframe (#privacyPolicy)*

```
<iframe
    name="privacy-policy" 
    id="privacy-policy"
    [src]="myURL"
    #privacyPolicy>
</iframe>
```

*In my Component I used @ViewChild to get access to my iframe*

```
export class MyClass implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('privacyPolicy', { static: false }) privacyPolicy: ElementRef<any>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const hostElement = this.privacyPolicy.nativeElement;
    console.log(hostElement.children);
    console.log(hostElement.parentNode);
    console.log('iframe', this.privacyPolicy.nativeElement.style.border = '1px solid black');
  }
}
```

The third `console.log()` inside the `ngAfterViewInit()` lifecycle is working and styles the iframe-Element. But I want to style the html-Element nested inside the iframe-Element.

I've already tried it like this (no success):

```
hostElement.children[0].style.border = "1px solid black";
```

Is there a clean and easy Angular way to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

You need to access to contentDocument and after you will have your content HTML from Iframe.
In your case:

```
const hostElement = this.privacyPolicy.nativeElement;
hostElement.contentDocument.body.style.border = '1px solid black';
```

and if you want to add a new style to your iframe

```
  const hostElement = this.privacyPolicy.nativeElement;
  const iframe = hostElement.contentDocument;
  const style = document.createElement('style');
  let newStyle = 'body {background-color: red;}';
  style.innerText = newStyle;
  iframe.head.appendChild(style);
```

Comment: This way I get: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of undefined. I think its because hostElement.contentDocument returns #document instead of the needed html-Tag. And the html-Tag is nested inside the returned #document.

Comment: em okay I think it's necessary to use pure javascript like the example -->
const iframe = (document.getElementById('previewPage') as HTMLIFrameElement);

Comment: I forgot to put privacy-policy in getElementById